# How To Add A String Inside An Object For The Given Example

Tags: javascript

Hi iam finding the best way to add a string inside the given object.Any help would be appreciated

my String is 'created'

Down Below Is My Data

```
{
    "id": "222",
    "list": [
        {
            "name": "Tony",
      
        }
    ],
```

iam trying to insert 'created' in the data like this

```
 {
    "id": "222",
    "list": [
        {
            "name": "Tony",
            "type":"created"
      
        }
    ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const myObj = {
    "id": "222",
    "list": [
        {
            "name": "Tony",
  
        }
    ], 
};
myObj.list[0].type = "created";
```

This is the way you can do this. But you'd better use secified `index` of `list` items;

```
const index = 0; // Or any other way to get this

myObj.list[index].type = "created";
```

Answer (score 1):

The string you've provided looks a lot like JSON data. You can convert a JSON string to an actual javascript object by using the `JSON.parse(string)` method.

With this object we then can query it's `list` property - which in your case is an array of objects - and add a new property `type` to each of the arrays elements. The final step is converting the object back to a JSON string using the `JSON.stringify(object)` method.

Here's an example:

```js
let str = `{
    "id": "222",
    "list": [
        {
            "name": "Tony" 
        }
    ]
  }`;
let data = JSON.parse(str);
data.list.forEach(element => {
  element.type = "created";
});
str = JSON.stringify(data);
console.log(str);
```